# Solving for K so that it has 2 distinct eigenvectors and a eigenvalue of 2?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Hello so I am working on this question below and I know how to solve for the eigenvalues and vectors but don't know how to reverse engineer it and solve for a term in a vector I could really use some help thank you.

For the matrix A below, find a value of k so that A has two basic eigenvectors associated with the eigenvalue λ = −2?[image]

Comment: $-2$ is already an eigenvalue, regardless of the value of $k$. Find the eigenvectors as normal, selecting $k$ so that you get two independent eigenvectors.

Comment: How do I solve for a k so that there are two eigenvectors that is what is tripping me up?

Comment: Since $(1,0,0,0)^T$ is already an eigenvector, you may try to find some $k$ such that the last three columns of $A+2I$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: Write down the equations you would have to solve. You should be able to see what $k$ is "by inspection" (note the fourth coordinate of a solution has to be $0$ and the second and third have to be equal). Also, keep user1551's comment in mind.

Comment: All these terms are confusing me I don't know if I understand